# Advance Android Concepts

Tags: android, kotlin

As we know that Android Development is becoming quite easy with Android's new concepts like :

1. Android Architecture Patterns,
2. RxJava, RxBus,
3. Two Way Data binding,
4. Room,
5. Live Data,
6. Kotlin Coroutines,
7. Dagger,
8. Data Store,
9. JetPack Library,
10. Work Manager,
11. Navigation and Flow,
12. Motion Layouts,
    and many more...

There are many documents available to get known about these concepts But, at some level I got confused.

Is there any dependency among these concepts?
I just want to go through all with proper steps and complete guidelines.

**Can anybody guide me that How can I start Step by Step to complete these concepts with 100% clarity?**

Comment: _"There are many documents available to get known about these concepts But, at some level I got confused."_ Then ask a more focused question on exactly that confusing part of that specific concept. This isn't a question that could be properly answered. You get 100% clarity on the concepts by reading about them and trying them out in some dummy (or real) app. and asking more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

I can assist you about concepts which I am aware of.

1. **Android Architecture Patterns,Live Data,View Model** :

   Mostly now a days Developers are using MVVM architecture.So,better to start with MVVM pattern where you will come across ViewModel and LiveData concepts.So,these are basic components in MVVM.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#0

Sample Viewmodel class can be found in below link.

https://github.com/TarunAnchala/News-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/assigment/newsapp/NewsViewModel.java

2. **Room**

   Room is the wrapper over sqlite which makes developer work easy.I am sure that once you start using Room you won't go back to sqlite.

https://android.jlelse.eu/5-steps-to-implement-room-persistence-library-in-android-47b10cd47b24

Sample Room Implementation in below link.

https://github.com/TarunAnchala/News-App/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/assigment/newsapp/db

3. **Work Manager**

Work Manager is very easy to implement and it can be finished in 15 to 30mins.

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-workmanager-tutorial/

4. **Motion Layouts**

Motion layout is used to implement animations very easily.In below blog,Siva had explained well.

https://medium.com/better-programming/beginners-guide-to-motion-layout-732395a7de7e